# Yii2. Invalid path alias

Tags: yii2

I've seen similiar questions but haven't found a working solution. Here is my index.php file:

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();

require(__DIR__ . '/../config/aliases.php');
```

As you can see, it requires `config/aliases.php` file, whose contents are:

```
<?php

Yii::setAlias('message_files_root', '@webroot/message_files');
Yii::setAlias('message_files', '@web/message_files');
```

Calling`Yii::getAlias('@message_files_root')` works fine within the `index.php`, but when it is in a controller file, it says `Invalid path alias: @message_files_root`.

Here is my controller's action (the rest of the code is fully commented):

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    var_dump(Yii::getAlias('@message_files_root'));

    $message = new Message();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am NOT claiming that is the nicest way to do that, but it works the way I wanted it to work – when an alias can include other aliases.

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

$app = new class($config) extends yii\web\Application
{
    protected function bootstrap()
    {
        parent::bootstrap();

        require(__DIR__ . '/../config/aliases.php');
    }
};

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 2):

if you invoke Yii::getAlias() static method from controller, Yii::setAlias(@web) does not get register yet.
you may refer to the web/index file.

web/index.php

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php'); --> Yii::setAlias(@web) are not listed here
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
//var_dump(Yii::getAlias('@web'));die; --> imitate invoke @web alias fail
$application->run(); --> here both @web alias and aliases from $config got registered.
//var_dump(Yii::getAlias('@web'));die; --> imitate invoke @web alias success
```

my guess is, the config got registered first before the default @web aliases being register. Thats why invoking @web aliases from bootrap config fail.
thus, u need to use absolute path for the second paramter. use this..

yii2 advanced template

```
Yii::setAlias('@message_files_root', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend/web/message_files');
```

yii2 basic template

```
Yii::setAlias('@message_files_root', dirname(__DIR__) . '/web/message_files');
```

Comment: I've put the last piece of code into the `aliases.php` file, but it's no use, even if it doesn't rely on any other aliases..

Comment: did your `aliases.php` were listed in `web/index.php`?